# Paramiko: Piping blocks forever on read

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I have a problem with getting piping to work with paramiko.

This works:

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
[...]
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("find /tmp")
stdout.read()
```

This does **not** work (blocks forever on stdout.read()):

```
[...]
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("bash -")
stdin.write("find /tmp\n")
stdin.close()
stdout.read()
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I looked at the source code for paramiko, and ChannelFile.close does not really do anything in terms of communication. So I looked at the channel API, and this seems to work:

```
stdin.write("find /tmp\n")
stdin.flush()
stdin.channel.shutdown_write()
stdout.read()
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With some investigation, it appears that `stdin.close()` does not actually end the bash session.  To do that, you could use the bash command `exit` (`stdin.write('exit\n')`) or dig into the paramiko `Channel` object underneath the `stdin` object:

```
stdin.channel.shutdown_write()
```

If you'd like the bash session to continue for another command, you'll need to use the channel object directly.  The [documentation for `Channel`](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.Channel-class.html) mentions `recv_ready(self)` and `recv(self, nbytes)` which will allow you t check for the data before you try to get it.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out myself already, but SO does not let me answer my own qestions yet :-)