# Paramiko hang when use ssh-keygen command

Tags: python, unix, ssh, paramiko

I am creating one user and want to set the ssh key for that user

My script is

```
import paramiko

ssh_conn = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_conn.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_conn.load_system_host_keys()
ssh_conn.connect('localhost', username='test', password='test')

cmd = 'ssh-keygen -t dsa'

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_conn.exec_command(cmd)
stdin.write('\n')
stdin.flush()
stdin.write('\n')
stdin.flush()
stdin.write('\n')
stdin.flush()

print "Output: ", stdout.read()
```

But its seems not working

When i run it as single statement copy past on python console then it works but when i run it as single python script it hang at last line `print "Output: ", stdout.read()`.

Thx in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before attempting to read the `stdout` issue:

```
stdin.channel.shutdown_write()
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8052840/146792) for reference.

Comment: Hi @mac if i will not write `stdout.read()` after the `stdin.channel.shutdown_write()` and perform some other task then it will not generate `.pub` file at that time. Means is there any way to check that command complete its execution?